# SOAP request works in SoapUI but doesn't work in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap

I am trying to reach a SOAP API using Node.

Using SoapUI I can reach it without a problem, and this is the request:

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:axis="http://ws.apache.org/axis2">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <axis:getKey>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <axis:user>email@email.com</axis:user>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <axis:password>password</axis:password>
      </axis:getKey>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

However, using the `soap` package, an error is thrown every single time: Cannot parse response.

The XML of the request, however, is pretty much the same:

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns="http://ws.apache.org/axis2" xmlns:ax21="http://rpc.xml.coldfusion/xsd" xmlns:ns1="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:ax22="http://rpc.xml.coldfusion/xsd">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns:getKey xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/axis2">
         <ns:user>email@email.com</ns:user>
         <ns:password>password</ns:password>
      </ns:getKey>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I tried it in SoapUI and it's working perfectly! I don't understand why I am getting the error!

This is my code:

```
async method(userData) {
    const wsdl = 'http://www.maxbounty.com/api.cfc?wsdl';
    const client = await soap.createClientAsync(wsdl);
    const test = await client.getKeyAsync({ user: userData.username, password: userData.password });
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised that SoapUI formatted the body in a different way. I copy-pasted the body it was using on my code, and it worked like a charm.